# How to execute a shell script using CMake post_build?

Tags: c, linux, cmake

How to execute a shell script using CMake? The command that should be run is `my_script` that should be executed after build. The `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(abc)

include_directories("/usr/lib/avr/include")

set(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR /home/user/Desktop)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mmcu=atmega8")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)

add_executable(abc ${SOURCE_FILES})

#not working ----->
add_custom_command(TARGET abc
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E my_script
        )
```

**DISCLAIMER**

Yes, there are similar questions in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961650/use-cmake-to-run-a-c-program-post-build), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091447/run-command-after-generation-step-in-cmake), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354473/cmake-add-custom-command/2362222#2362222), etc; however, they don't give me a clear vision how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are invoking CMake with it's [command-line tool mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) which doesn't execute generic scripts or commands.

Instead do e.g.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET abc
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND /bin/sh /path/to/my_script
        )
```

Comment: Elegant answer, just perfect :)

Comment: Is there a way to use a relative, instead of an absolute path to the script?

Comment: @MattKelly Of course, but the relatives paths will be from the build directory. Better use one of the CMake directory variables instead (like `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` or similar).